# Limiting the maximum number of pods per deployment within a namespace / cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am attempting to enforce a limit on the number of pods per deployment within a namespace / cluster from a single configuration point. I have two non-production environments, and I want to deploy fewer replicas on these as they do not need the redundancy.

I've read [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/quota-pod-namespace/) but I'm unable to find out how to do it on the deployment level. Is it possible to enforce this globally without going into each one of them?

Comment: Hi Alex, to understand the context, do you mean the deployment is created manually or there is some automation for creating those deployment resources?

Personally, I will create only 1 replica for the non-production environment.

Comment: Hi Eric, deployment is automated through CI, but I was wondering if I could avoid the change on the per-repo level, and apply it globally across my clusters / namespaces.

Comment: Hi Alex, This seems to a feature request for Kubernetes. I recommend you to create one through the [github.com](https://github.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Since the replicas is a fixed value on a deployment YAML file, you may better to use [helm](https://helm.sh/) to make a template for adding some flexibility in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this,

```
$ kubectl autoscale deployment <deployment-name> --min=1 --max=3 --cpu-percent=80 --namespace=<dev|staging>
```

Here, you can set the upper limit of the pod count for your deployment.